# Installed Apache (httpd) using Home Brew, but cannot seem to get mod_rewrite working?

Tags: catalina, homebrew, apache, webserver

I'm running macOS 10.15 (Catalina) and have installed the latest Apache (2.4.43) using `brew`, basically following [these steps](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-macos-homebrew/).

It seems to be working OK, I can visit http://localhost/ and when I change `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` (e.g. different port, different DocumentRoot, etc) and `sudo apachectl restart`, the changes are reflected in my local webserver.

However I also uncommented this line in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

But putting a `.htaccess` file in my DocumentRoot and defining some RewriteRules there does not seem to have any effect. Already did `sudo apachectl restart` but no difference.

`mod_rewrite.so` seems to be present, that is assuming that `lib/httpd/modules/` in my `httpd.conf` refers to `/usr/local/lib/httpd/modules`.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I enable mod_rewrite?

(edit) as reference, here are my `.htaccess` contents:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule test index.html [R=301,L,QSA]
```

1. I can visit `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, that works fine. ✅
2. When visiting `http://localhost:8080/` I get the directory index (list of files), not the index.html page as I would expect from the `DirectoryIndex` line. ❌
3. When visiting `http://localhost:8080/test` I get 'Not Found', not the index.html page as I would expect from the `RewriteRule`. ❌

(edit2) For what it's worth, if I do `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` it shows a list of loaded modules and it includes `rewrite_module`.

Comment: @klanomath How do you mean properly configure? I've edited my post and added the .htaccess contents + some test results.

Comment: @klanomath Thanks, did that (and edited .htaccess in post accordingly) but no difference unfortunately. Note that `sudo apachectl -k restart` says "httpd: illegal option -- k". Tried without `-k`, and also tried `sudo apachectl stop` and then `sudo apachectl start` separately. But still no difference.

Comment: @klanomath But if I do `sudo apachectl -v` it says `2.4.43` i.e. the version I installed with `brew` (without `sudo` same result by the way). Is there a way to be sure? `which apachectl` tells me `/usr/local/bin/apachectl`.

Comment: I ran a second test with [htaccess_tester.php on GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bolt/htaccess_tester/master/htaccess_tester.php) which requires to brew install php, brew start php **and** add some lines to /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf and it works. If you send me your /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf I can do the *annual service* and compare it with mine. email: klanomath(at)googlemail.com

Comment: Sorry my bad on the `-k` error, I must have made a typo or something, `sudo apachectl -k restart` actually does work (doesn't make the RewriteRule working though). Have placed [my httpd.conf here](https://pastebin.com/raw/8E7btE5E), much appreciated! 

Comment: I think it's the AllowOverride directive in your line 271 which should be **All**! Some other differences: I use $whoami/staff instead of _www/_www (which is rather unrelated)

Comment: @klanomath Thanks, I thought I tried that already, but I have been swapping some things back and forward (going back to the `/usr/local/var/www/` dir in case it had something to do with permissions, but changed back to my home dir again later) and it's working now! Much appreciated ♥

Comment: Besides permission problems with _www/_www  accessing user folders (/Users/rocketnuts/TestSites/...), the compelling reason that mod_rewrite doesn't work is the AllowOverride directive in my env: *When this directive (AllowOverride) is set to None and AllowOverrideList is set to None, .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.* [Source](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the permission on line 271 from none to all and worked out

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```